# How can I find the distortion/anomaly in a textured image using Image processing?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

Consider the following image1 and image2 . Both have some defects in them. My approach was to to use GLCM matrix and use the properties like energy or dissimilarity to find the distortion.
Below is a part of the code i used.

```
 stepSize = w
(w_width, w_height) = (w, w) # window size
for y in range(0, image.shape[0]-w, stepSize):
    u=u+1
    for x in range(0, image.shape[1]-w, stepSize):
      k=k+1
      print(k)
      
      window = image[y:y + w, x:x + w]
      glcm = greycomatrix(window, d, theta, levels)
      f1.append(greycoprops(glcm, 'correlation')) 
      f2.append(greycoprops(glcm, 'energy'))
      f3.append(greycoprops(glcm, 'homogeneity'))
      f4.append(greycoprops(glcm, 'contrast'))
      f5.append(greycoprops(glcm, 'dissimilarity'))
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nySyl.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSRiL.jpg)

i am using a non overlapping sliding window over the image and compute glcm for each window. But if i take 'energy' property values of these sub windows in the image, and try to plot them wrt the windows, i am not getting a distinctive variation / spike in that particiular window with defect.
The problem is  i cannot distinguish clearly both defective and non defective images based on these glcm properties. Should i use any different algorithm? is there a better way without using neural network?